# ddrescue in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, ddrescue

I want to copy from a damaged external HDD having a size of 500GB. I will use `ddrescue` for this.

Can I use like the following: I want to copy only one directory(named 'Important Docs') from 500GB HDD. 'Important Docs' has a size of 1GB. So in my laptop, I have a disk with space 20GB, can I image the 1GB 'Important Docs' folder to the 20GB HDD?

Comment: Last time I looked ddrescue doesn't know anything about the filesystem.  You may look for a different tool.

Comment: @Zoredache Could you please suggest another one...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [commandlinefu](http://www.commandlinefu.com/commands/view/4553/copy-a-file-using-dd-and-watch-its-progress): Copy a file using dd and watch its progress.

> dd if=/path/to/important/docs of=tofile & DDPID=$! ; sleep 1 ; while kill -USR1
>   $DDPID ; do sleep 5; done

I think (not tested) that if you change the path of if to a directory MAYBE it could work. 
If you make a google search you'll read that [this is the wrong way](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/VALinux-kb/copying-directory-trees.html) to do this.
In the same pages you can read that "there is no attempt to map around bad sectors on physical media" so i think it won't work but you don't have nothing to lose.

The use of the "of" and the options of "dd" could be as shown in [this page](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/learn-the-dd-command-362506/):

> dd if=/path/to/important/docs of=/your/harddisk/myCD.iso bs=2048 conv=sync,notrunc
>
> mkdir /mnt/myCD
>
> mount -o loop /home/sam/myCD.iso /mnt/myCD

you'll create an .iso image, then create the directory to mount the image and mount the image.

good luck!